# How to create a RSpec task with Rspec 2?

Tags: rspec, task

Using tspec 2 I want to create a rake task on the fly to be run, we used to do the following in RSpec 1:

```
Spec::Rake::SpecTask.new(:client) do |t|
  t.spec_files = FileList['spec/units/client/**/*_spec.rb']
  t.spec_opts = spec_opts
end
```

But now Spec::Rake::SpecTask was substituted, any suggestions?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The task name now is [Rspec::Core::RakeTask](http://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/blob/master/lib/rspec/core/rake_task.rb) task, as in

```
Rspec::Core::RakeTask.new(:client) do |t|
  t.pattern = ".spec/units/client/**/*_spec.rb"
  t.spec_opts = spec_opts
end
```